# Temp wall to support wide opening in exterior wall

Tags: walls, doors, framing, door-frame, engineering

I'm putting in an 11' wide door opening in a walkout basement exterior wall. There are 2 more floors above the basement. I have the engineered sized steel beam as the header.

Can I do a 2x6 temp wall, studs directly under each floor joist, about 2' in from the existing exterior wall to be on top of, and parallel to the basement floor joist below.

The floor joists in the basement floor that will support the temp wall run parallel to the exterior wall and are steel 2x6's. See pics below. If they were perpendicular I wouldn't think too much of it.

Below the floor is a dirt crawl space, so not too easy to support under the basement floor.

Thinking I could distribute the load across more of the floor joists if I put several 4x4's perpendicular to the basement floor joists to span 4 of them, then build the temp wall on top of that?

Any other ideas, thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds good, but with two floors above, why did you not have the engineer advise on the support wall when designing the header needed.  I doubt that any engineer without seeing the house will give advice over the internet.  You did use an engineer?

Comment: Ditto Crip's comments. This screams for an engineer to be involved.

Comment: @crip659 yeah I can ask the engineer that sized the steel header beam.

Comment: For the prices houses go for, you really do not want someone on the internet designing this.  But then I am surprised by people who try the stuff on tictok.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't take 1/2 the load of the floors above and transfer it to a single one of the crawl space 3" tall? metal joists.  If you are going 2' out I'd pick the point and make a pony wall in the crawl that takes the load to the slab.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger right. The joists are 2x6, not 3", but still that is too small. And there is no slab, just dirt below..the house is build on piers. I'm waiting on the engineer, but thinking to run 4x4 or 6x6 perpendicular to the floor joists and directly above the thick steel beams that the floor joists run perpendicular to. Then run a 6x6 perpendicular to those that will transfer the load across the 3 floor joists and then dirctly down to the steel beams.

Comment: I did temp wall on dirt...   just used 2x12 as base plate on temp wall to xfer load to dirt.  the metal ibeams in crawl are 2x6?  seem small compared to your hand with the tape - guess a perspective issue.  be interested to hear what you end up doing.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger I could do the temp wall on the dirt, but it is not un-disturbed soil and not compacted so it would settle a lot under load. Plus it is all covered by thick plastic for radon mitigation, and it is no where near level, but that is moot compared to not being compacted. It is an intersting dilema for sure. Still waiting on the engineer :(

Comment: my dirt wasn't compacted either was pretty much just top soil.  I did use screw jack posts though and I put them under tension before removing a 1960 foundation wall (which was also built on top soil).  I suppose with the screw jacks in my case even if the load had deflected down an inch I could have pushed it back up with the screw jacks.   The point of the 2x12 bottom plate was to distribute the load to the crappy soil.  Even on mud soil you can build a raft foundation and effectively float your house.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger thanks, the screw jacks are a great idea.